# Generating script from existing table having too much detail

Tags: sql-server

When i use SQL Server Management Studio GUI to generate script of a table of an existing database, it produces the following:

```
USE [BikeStores]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [production].[brands2]    Script Date: 9/20/2019 3:44:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [production].[brands2](
    [brand_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [brand_name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [brand_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

But i want the simple table script as follows

```
CREATE TABLE production.brands2 (
    brand_id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    brand_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: So just copy and paste that part out, or use a database project and define your database objects yourself in that. You can't change the way that SSMS creates the scripts. It creates the most verbose version intentionally.

Comment: Why do you want such a script?

Comment: You can't have such a script (not from SMSS at least), because not all options possible on all indexes and constraints can be squished into a simple `CREATE TABLE`. If you want a simple and possibly not representative script that won't cover all options, you'll need to write your own code for it (or find some third-party scripting tool that does).

Comment: I can not understand what is the purpose of such a script? Let's say that there is a sense. But it is not easy to get the expected result by changing 'SQL Server Object Explorer->Scripting' options, as suggested in the answer. What's more it is not easy to get the desired result by using SMO with .NET ( CORE). So, if we skip the copy-paste-edit solution,  at the end of the story is the only possibility to start using VS and to code the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to create the desired output in SSMS. **However**, you can do some slight changes in SSMS of what to output when you script your table. For example you can choose not to
Script Indexes, Triggers and Foreign keys. Etc..

Go to Tools -> Options -> Sql Server Object Explorer -> Scripting